# Is a humming sink disposal motor failing?

Tags: garbage-disposal

Ok so this is a strange question about my garbage disposal. I had my kitchen cabinets replaced but kept my original sink and garbage disposal. Its approximately 20 years old. When I went to use it, it only made a "humming noise". I have troubleshooted garbge disposals before so I know what I'm looking for. So I took an alen key and turned the motor and and pressed the reset button (since it popped). But didn't have any luck.

The next morning I try it one more time and the thing fires right up!? I'm at a loss of what happened, anyone ever have this issue ?

Comment: Failing motors often do so at specific points in the rotation. Temperature can also affect startup due to expansion of metal.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the disposer or re-plumb the drains to do without one. A 20-year-old disposer that is not working is not worth repairing.